# SocketException: No Connection Could be Made Because The Target Machine Actively Refused it

Tags: c#, sockets, exception, tcp

So, I've seen several questions on Stackoverflow that have to do with this, but (a) none of them solved my problem, and (b) they weren't doing what I was doing in most of them. So, I have a client and server windows forms application, and I just want to get them connected. Here's the code for the server:

```
private void connectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Attempt to connect
    try {
        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipBox.Text);
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ip, 8000);
        listener.Start();
        messageBox.Text = "Server started! Waiting for connection...";
        messageBox.Refresh();
        Socket socket = listener.AcceptSocket();
        messageBox.Text += "\nConnection accepted from " + socket.RemoteEndPoint;
    }
    catch (Exception eg) {
        messageBox.Text = Convert.ToString(eg);
    }
}
```

This all works great, I would include more about getting the IP and all that, but it's pretty straightforward and I already know that that works. So when you run this, and press the connect button, it basically sends the message that it's started. Here's the code for the client:

```
private void connectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient();
        messageBox.Text = "Connecting....";
        messageBox.Refresh();
        tcp.Connect(ipBox.Text, 8001);
        messageBox.Text += "\nConnected!";
        messageBox.Refresh();
    }
    catch (Exception eg) {
        messageBox.Text += Convert.ToString(eg);
        messageBox.Refresh();
    }
}
```

This sends that it is connecting, and then a few seconds later the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV6EK.png). I hear this is because the server isn't listening (I've already let the program through the firewall), but I have this on the server: `Socket socket = listener.AcceptSocket();`. How can I fix this?

Comment: You are connecting to 8001 while the server is listening on 8000?

Comment: Thanks! I actually looked at that before I posted this, but I thought they were both 8001. It works now!